# more than one recyclerview integrated in one page of a viewpager

Tags: java, android

I am somewhat new to android development and I am working on my final year project.

I have this problem, and I don't have a clue how this from the images [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rcos.jpg) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i4m3.jpg) [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNgw2.jpg) was achieved. The way I see it, it looks like a viewpager but it has 3 recycler views probably in a linear layout in each view.

Now my problem is that I have only done a viewpager which will use values from one Jsonarray item for each view in the vp. I might be looking at it the wrong way so I would appreciate any other theories to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between these 3 tabs is the data. You have the same item everywhere. I would suggest to implement 1 Fragment which will hold 1 RecyclerView and all the logic to set items to Adapter, handle click events etc.

But you need to pass the actual array of elements to this Fragment from outside, no logic for getting data from some source should be written in Fragment.

And in your activity, you should have get the actual data, for example 3 Arraylists of Items, then you need to have a ViewPager, and add 3 instances of the Fragment to this ViewPager with different list of items.

In general that's it. If you need more details, well first provide more details and just let me know.

Comment: Thats for answering

Comment: Thanks for answering in the example 3 Arraylists of Items how will i achieve this is it during querying the database sql code or after recieving the json array in java and is it better if the items are fixed or dynamic